# Can I add a logo to every slide of a xaringan template using css?

Tags: xaringan

I would like to adapt the .css file provided [here](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/blob/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/xaringan/resources/rutgers.css) to include a small logo in the top right corner of every slide except the title, inverse, and final slide. Ideally, I can just add something simple to the .css file rather than manually code each slide of the presentation.

I tried adding this

```
background-image: url(https://github.com/jvcasillas/ru_xaringan/raw/master/img/logo/ru_shield.png);
  background-position: 9% 15%;
  background-size: 55px;
```

to

```
.remark-slide-content {
  padding-left: 100px;  /* delete this for 4:3 aspect ratio */
}
```

to get

```
.remark-slide-content {
background-image: url(https://github.com/jvcasillas/ru_xaringan/raw/master/img/logo/ru_shield.png);
  background-position: 9% 15%;
  background-size: 55px;
  padding-left: 100px;  /* delete this for 4:3 aspect ratio */
}
```

the image shows up on all slides including the title and transition. It even over-rides the .title-slide image.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following to exclude the `title-slide`:

```
.remark-slide-content:not(.title-slide){
  background-image: url(https://github.com/jvcasillas/ru_xaringan/raw/master/img/logo/ru_shield.png);
  background-position: 9% 15%;
  background-size: 55px;
  padding-left: 100px;  /* delete this for 4:3 aspect ratio */
}
```

but the downside of this is that if you have a background image in other slides, it will overwrite the image above. So you may like to define another class, e.g. `exclude` as well:

```
.remark-slide-content:not(.exclude){
  background-image: url(https://github.com/jvcasillas/ru_xaringan/raw/master/img/logo/ru_shield.png);
  background-position: 9% 15%;
  background-size: 55px;
  padding-left: 100px;  /* delete this for 4:3 aspect ratio */
}

.logopos {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9%;
  left: 15%;
}
```

and for the corresponding slide that you have an issue with another background image disable this and add it manually. E.g.

```
class: exclude 
background-image: url("bla")

content

<img class="logopos" src="https://github.com/jvcasillas/ru_xaringan/raw/master/img/logo/ru_shield.png">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Emi. The first approach you provided works as expected and excludes a logo from the title slide while putting it on all the other slides. Unfortunately it doesn't remove it from slides of class inverse which I'd also like to have it disappear for a more obvious transition. The second approach removes the logo from the slides when I manually disable it (i.e. class: exclude) but then it appears in the title slide.

Comment: You can repeat the first one replacing `not(.title-slide)` with `not(.inverse)` to prevent the logo in inverse ones.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I repeat the first example with `not(.inverse)` the small logo does still appear on pages of class inverse.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I ran into the package `xaringanExtra` by Garrick Aden-Buie, see https://pkg.garrickadenbuie.com/xaringanExtra/. Lots of useful functionalities, including a very easy logo handling option. You just add a chunk

````
```{r xaringan-logo, echo=FALSE}
xaringanExtra::use_logo(
image_url = <fill in your path> )
```
````

and that is all.